# Is it possible to programmatically execute JSON queries with C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

As the title says: is it possible?

You should think of the following scenario: I press a button in ASP.NET -> some C# backend -> Execute a JSON string

So something like this:

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string check = (string)(Session["usr"])

       if(check == null;)
       {
          // Execute JSON
       }
       else
       {
          Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
       }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By execute json you mean javascript? If so try registerstartupscript

Comment: @misha130 JSON is JavaScript (Javascript Object Notation)

Comment: Yes I underdtood my mistake after writing that

Comment: JSON certainly is not JavaScript. And you can't execute JSON. JSON is a data format, like XML, but has near identical syntax to definding objects in JavaScript (hence the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this method

```
RegisterStartupScript(scriptname, jsonstring);
```

This will put the script on top of the html page. 
Further read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx